# How do I take a screenshot of the current view of my desktop app in Unity using C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, desktop-application

I have a desktop application that I have made on Unity and I want to take a screenshot of my current view in the application using a C# script attached to the main camera. Please help.

I have browsed other code snippets that I found on this platform and nothing seemed to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [CaptureScreenshot](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot.html).

```cs
public class ScreenCapture : MonoBehaviour
{
    //here you can set the folder you want to use, 
    //IMPORTANT - use "@" before the string, because this is a verbatim string
    //IMPORTANT - the folder must exists
    string pathToYourFile = @"C:\Screenshots\";
    //this is the name of the file
    string fileName = "filename";
    //this is the file type
    string fileType = ".png";

    private int CurrentScreenshot { get => PlayerPrefs.GetInt("ScreenShot"); set => PlayerPrefs.SetInt("ScreenShot", value); }

    private void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            UnityEngine.ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(pathToYourFile + fileName + CurrentScreenshot + fileType);
            CurrentScreenshot++;
        }
    }
}
```

A few notes.

1. I used a verbatim string to define your folder
2. The folder where you store the screenshot must exist (if you want to create it in the script [you can follow this answer](https://answers.unity.com/questions/528641/how-do-you-create-a-folder-in-c.html))
3. *AFTER COMMENT REQUEST - 1*: If you do not set the folder the file will be saved in the default directory of the application (that changes based on the system - you can check it from [Application.dataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html))
4. *AFTER COMMENT REQUEST - 2*: If you use the same path and filename the file will be overriden, so I added a way to let you save multiple screenshots, also in different sessions using [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).

Comment: Where does this store the image? How can I get access to it?

Comment: Code updated to let you choose where to store the screenshot.

Comment: Is there any way I can keep my previous screenshot and store new ones as well? Because right now it is replacing the old one.

Comment: We're going out of this answer scope :). I've added the code to let you save multiple screenshots. I added also the playerprefs to let you keep saing the screenshots also if you close and re open the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CaptureScreenshot method as answered above but it might be confusing for you if you are new to unity. It stores your captures image in a filepath which you should pass to CaptureScreenshot method as parameter for example

```
public class ScreenShotManager : MonoBehaviour {

const string FilePath = @"C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\ScreenShots";

public void CaptureScreenShot() {
    ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(FilePath);
}

void Update(){
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(Keycode.C))
        CaptureScreenShot();
}
```

this code shows that if you press 'c' key on keyboard it would be captured what main camera is rendering at that moment and stored in that file path

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I am receiving an error with this code. It says failed to store screen shot at the file location that I have given. I copied the address from the folder itself, so I dont know why this is happening

Comment: Nevermind, I missed out on a bit. Thank you so much for your help.